# JSP DataBase Result Not Displaying Properly

Tags: mysql, html, database, jsp, jstl

I have a JSP MySQL query

```
<sql:query var="libraries" dataSource="jdbc/ArabiTagOnline"><br>
     SELECT l.LibraryId, v1.LAvalue AS "dbESTid", v2.LAValue AS "LibName", v3.LAValue AS "Desc" 
     FROM ((Library l LEFT JOIN LibAttrValue v1 ON l.LibraryId = v1.LibraryId AND v1.AttributeId = 1) 
     LEFT JOIN LibAttrValue v2 ON l.LibraryId = v2.LibraryId AND (v2.AttributeId = 2 OR v2.AttributeId IS NULL))
     LEFT JOIN LibAttrValue v3 ON l.LibraryId = v3.LibraryId AND (v3.AttributeId = 6 OR v3.AttributeId IS NULL)
<\sql:query
```

This returns four columns.
I tried to rename the columns in the results with AS but when iterating over the results

```
<c:forEach var="libraryResults" items="${libraries.rows}">
    <tr>
        <td>${libraryResults.Libraryid}</td>
        <td>${libraryResults.dbESTid}</td>
        <td>${libraryResults.LibName}</td>
        <td>${libraryResults.Desc}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

When loading the page, the columns `dbESTid`, `LibName` and `Desc` are blank.
I asked `${libraries.columnNames}` and found out the AS statement in my query didn't rename the columns, they are all still LAValue. `${libraryResults.LAValue}` only returns Desc. Any help on how I can populate this table?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need double quotes around column aliases in your SQL - that may be confusing the jdbc driver. Also, why the break tag within the `<sql-query>`?

Column aliasing *should* work. However, if the problem persists one possible workaround is to iterate over columns within each row:

```
<c:forEach var="libraryResults" items="${libraries.rows}">
  <tr>
    <c:forEach var="column" items="${libraryResults}">
      <td><c:out value="${column.value}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

That said, the **real** solution is, of course, to use an MVC framework so you don't have to embed your queries in JSP.